# ng-select multiple resets ngModel array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, angular-ngselect

I have implemented the ng-select on my angular project and so far it's working great. But it's having a behavior that I need to change and I'm not see anything on the project documentation.

In the first image, I'm using the `multiple` input. The data being display comes from an API that has the following structure:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'apple',
    size: 1,
    unit: ml,
    position: 1
}
```

The data is displayed correctly and so far is ok. The issue comes after trying to add/remove an item. Every time I add/remove a value the whole array is recreated and only left the `id` and `name` values, and the other ones are blank as I show in the second picture.

To "fix" this I'm cloning the previous state of the array and using `(add)` and `(remove)` inputs to try to set the data correctly on my own, assigning the previous state plus the new item. But I had to the same on deleting items.

Any idea on how I can maintain my data without rewriting everything?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngselect-data-reset?file=src/bindings-default-example.component.html)

[image: initial state]
[image: after adding a new item]

Comment: Could you please share your issue through https://stackblitz.com/. I think that would be more clear.

Comment: I created one, where you can see the behavior on how "resets" the whole data.

Comment: I suggest you one thing, why don't you use ingredients object to update the value, I mean 

make {
      id: 272,
      name: 'acelga',
      size: '',
      unit: '',
      position: 0
    }
like this, and update the value to this object only when you fetch the value from input.

Comment: Give me some time I will update your code.

Comment: I would suggest going with two different data sources.

Since `ng-select` provides `add` and `remove` event. Use a different array to bind to the lower list, and add and remove the items would simply push the object into the list array. And remove() method would remove the object from the list array.

Comment: @j4rey thats what I'm doing, I did some work around like keeping a copy of the array before modifying it and manually pushing the new object and assigning the array again, but because I use this component on CREATE and EDIT, seems to be a little bit of extra work just for that, and I wash hoping `ng-select` could handle that.